# Get an array index in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

How would I get an array position in php?

I have an array:

```
$arr = array("mp3", "wma");
```

and a for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++ ) {
{
    $_POST['extention_file'.$i] = pathinfo($_FILES[ 'file'.$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // getting file extension here
    // i know this in java script: 
    //    flag_extFile = file.name.split(".").pop();
    //    flag_extFile = flag_extFile.toLowerCase();
    //    flag_extCheck = arr.indexOf(flag_extFile);
    // alert(flag_extCheck); we will get array index here.
    // how we can do the same functionality in php
}
```

How can I achieve this in php?

**Edited:**
I need the result without using a foreach loop or any other loop. In JavaScript I could write `arr.indexOf(flag_extFile);`, I need the same thing in php.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: where do u want to use $arr?

Comment: `how can i achieve this in php` What does `this` refer to here?

Comment: if you can see the js code. the result will be if **flag_extFile** is **mp3** then **flag_extCheck** value will be '0'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_search()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-search.php) to return the array key:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++ ) {
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES[ 'file'.$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $_POST['extention_file'.$i] = $ext;
    echo 'Key index is: ' . array_search($ext, $arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution

```
 $arr = array("mp3", "wma","cd");         

 echo array_search("cd",$arr);
```